# Loading a DLL from another DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dll, loadlibrary

I have a C++ - DLL A which is going to call another DLL B.
In case I use the command

```
LoadLibrary(L"...\\whole path\\B.dll");
```

everything is working fine. But assuming that sometimes the path may change due to maintenance reason for example I came up with

```
LoadLibraryEx("B.dll", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR);
```

to allow moving the DLLs without expecting loading problems.

This command is searching in the application's installations directory (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx).

Using Visual Studio 2010 Express it worked for me when I placed B.dll in the folder where the A.dll is saved.
Some days ago I installed Visual Studio 2015 Express. I placed the B.dll in the corresponding folder. It did not work. I copied it then into every other folder related to my A.dll though B.dll could not be found.

Note, both DLLs have been rewritten in VS2015! It is, thus, not a problem of different VS versions.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

**EDIT: (former problem understood, related question)**
After reading comments I found out this command redirects my DLL to search in Excels directory (which is calling A.dll).
But what I want to do is:
VBA will call a DLL A.dll by using an absolute path. All other DLLs like B.dll, C.dll, and so on will be in the same folder as A.dll. But those DLL I want to call giving a relative path. My intention is to change the path only once in the VBA code when I move all DLLs.
How do I do this?

Comment: Try disabling the "Visual Studio hosting process" in the debug settings to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: What does GetLastError say?

Comment: It's also worth to try Process Monitor from  Sysinternals tools  to check where actually this dll is being serched

Comment: The classical tool to debug DLL loading problems is Dependency Walker (Depends.EXE)

Comment: "Visual Studio hosting process" option is at Property Pages of the project, then Debugging, isnt it? I cant find it there..

Comment: I ckeck whether the hinstance is zero or not
if (!hinstDLL)...
there is no error message as such

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why you use `LoadLibraryEx`. `LoadLibrary` already search in the application directory; It is common to use `LoadLibrary("mydll.dll");`. You should use `GetCurrentDirectory` and `GetModuleFileName` to check where it is actually searching. Also, `LoadLibrary` WILL set an error, that you retrieve with `GetLastError`.

Comment: Ok GetLastError: **The specific module could not be found.** GetCurrentDrive: **The drive cannot locate a specific area or track on the disk.**

Comment: You need to print the output buffer of `GetCurrentDirectory` and `GetModuleFileName`, their return value is uninteresting. Just use a `char str[300]` as buffer parameters (the `LPTSTR` ones), and use this buffer in a `MessageBox` to see the search paths.

Comment: GetModuleFileName pointed out that my current drive is excel installation folder. Placing the dll in that folder is working. But my intention is that I will declare one DLL, e.g. A.dll in VBA. In the same folder next to A.dll there is B.dll, C.dll and so on. Those DLL I want to be called from A.dll but REGARDLESS their absolute path as long as they are always in the same folder. Is there any way to program that?

Comment: You could get the DLL directory by using `GetModuleFileName` with the `HMODULE` of DLL A, then deduce the path for the other DLLs and `LoadLibrary` with the absolute path. There are probably other ways too.